# Problem to have access to jquery plugin inside $(document).ready() with django-debug-toolbar

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-plugins

I wrote my own jquery plugin and was surprised that I haven't access to it inside $(document).ready function.

I wrote this testpage and was surprised even more:

```
//jQuery anchor plugin

(function ($) {
    $.anchor = {
        hashTrim: /^.*#/,
    }
})(jQuery);

console.log($.ajax);
console.log($.anchor);

$(function () {
    console.log($.ajax);
    console.log($.anchor);
});
```

I'v got 4 complettely different values in firebug console. Do somebody know and can describe me why is it so? And main question - how I can have access to my $.anchor variable inside $(function() {} ???

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I just catch the problem - django-debug-toolbar. When I disabled it, everythings gets fine!

Does anyone know how to make friendship between jquery and django-debug-toolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I partially solve this problem by switching to the another fork - [alex's django_debug_toolbar](http://github.com/alex/django-debug-toolbar/tree/master).

But I think it's more ugly, then [david cramer's django_debug_toolbar](http://github.com/dcramer/django-debug-toolbar/tree/master), that I use before and which contains this problem with jQuery. I hope to move functionality for avoiding this problem from alex's to dcramer's fork in future.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$.fn.anchor
```

Just tested your code sample, and both times the result is identical. But in general and for the future extend **$.fn** due to the fact it extends the jQuery object prototype. When you do just **$.anchor** you are just extending that instance of the object.

Comment: It gives me the same 2 values both times. I don't get the problem.

Comment: sorry, i catch error - django-debug-toolbar! thanks a lot! spasibo! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think that should be:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.anchor = {
        hashTrim: /^.*#/,
    }
})(jQuery);
```

**Edit:**

I get the same result both times too, same as the other guys.

Comment: sorry, i catch my problem - django-debug-toolbar! thanks a lot! spasibo! :-)